# Is there a name for this rhythm or does it come from something?

Tags: rhythm

Is there a name for this rhythm or does it come from something?  It almost sounds like triplets, but it's not.

[image]

Comment: It may not be immediately obvious that this question is a duplicate of the one proposed, but that question includes this one, and the answer can be found in the [post by GavinH](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/15113/70803).

Comment: Thank you.  The answer is in there, although the rhythm the OP posted was different and that answer is something "close" which is the thing I was asking about, which is apparently the tresillo.

Comment: Glad you got your answer. FWIW, the second rhythm of the two in the question is equivalent to yours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? This is specific to your rhythm of 12312312 - https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/39641/what-time-signature-has-3-out-of-8-beats-accented - it is called Calypso